# Checking if a Minecraft-Java server is cracked (in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, minecraft

I am trying to check in a **Python program**, if a ip/domain runs **a cracked - or **premium Minecraft server****.

I didn't found anything in the doc of packages like "[mcstatus](https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus)".
And I don't know, if it is even possible to get the information without logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try connecting to the server and watch the kick error?
I think [Mineflayer](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer) will do the job. It mainly uses node.js, but somehow is possible to code in python.

EDIT: Figured it out! You need [JSPyBridge](https://github.com/extremeheat/JSPyBridge).